# Pyspark One Hot Encoding

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sample data which I would like to do the PySpark version of str.get_dummies but am not sure how to do it.

title_df:

```
    Film       Category
    LOTR        Drama, Fantasy
    STAR WARS   Sci-Fi, Action
    etc.
```

Which will then give me with:

```
    Film     Action  Fantasy  Drama  Sci-Fi  Romance  Comedy
    LOTR          0       1        1      0        0       0
    STAR WARS     1       0        0      1        0       0
    etc.
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `crosstab`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = (df.select('Film', F.explode(F.split('Category', ', ')).alias('Category'))
         .distinct()
         .crosstab('Film', 'Category')
      )

df2.show()
+-------------+------+-----+-------+------+
|Film_Category|Action|Drama|Fantasy|Sci-Fi|
+-------------+------+-----+-------+------+
|         LOTR|     0|    1|      1|     0|
|    STAR WARS|     1|    0|      0|     1|
+-------------+------+-----+-------+------+
```

Or if you prefer classic Spark SQL operations:

```
df2 = (df.select('Film', F.explode(F.split('Category', ', ')).alias('Category'))
         .groupBy('Film')
         .pivot('Category')
         .agg(F.lit(1))
         .fillna(0)
      )
```

Comment: I didn't know this `crosstab` function. really nice. thx :)

Comment: @Steven it's just a syntactic sugar for groupby pivot and count :) I seldom find a use case for it though

Answer (score 3):

This is the ML way, for example:

```
%python

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder

stringIndexer = StringIndexer().setInputCol("ageCategory").setOutputCol("ageIndex")
ageModel = stringIndexer.fit(df)
df = ageModel.transform(df)
```